# Eclipse single line comment indentation inserted after the comment sign

Tags: eclipse, formatting, comments, auto-indent

This is the result after I used single line and block comment. The block one works fine, but on the single line, the indentation is inserted after the `//`:

```
    public static void checkN() {
//      int n;

        /*for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            n = getVal();
            assert n > 0: "n is negative";
            System.out.println("n: " + n);
        }*/
    }
```

However, the sample on the format setting does not have that problem:

[image]

The Eclipse version is **Spring Tool Suite** (**STS**). I'm not sure if it was the problem with any Spring framework plugins.

Comment: Did you check if your project has 'specific setting' enabled on 'Java code style -> Formatter'?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz No, it's not enabled.